# AWS Cognito Identity Pool: How to check if email attribute is verified or not

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Our android app currently requires admin to confirm users before logging in the app through aws cognito. Users can then successfully login even though the email attribute is not verified. I don't have a problem requesting verification code or verifying users using the verification code.

My problem is how to check if a currently logged-in email is verified or not?

I searched a lot but cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the user's attributes by calling `getDetails` on the `CognitoUser` instance providing it with a `GetDetailsHandler`. This handler will be called with map of user attributes. Look for the following attributes:

- `phone_number_verified`
- `email_verified`

  See the API docs here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/

**Note** Confirmation can also be automated using the `pre-signup` lambda hook - this is called `auto confirm`. See:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-pre-signup.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/signing-up-users-in-your-app.html#confirming-user-without-verification-of-email-or-phone-number